# How to set line height in xterm?

Tags: xterm

Coming from xfce4-terminal, one of the things I like the most was the ability to set the line height to give a bit more space/padding between each line.

Here's an example for what I'm referring to

[image: Example]

The terminal in the top-right with the blue background is xfce4 with the extra padding, compared to the top-left grey background xterm.

The open dialogue box shows "Cell spacing" height at 1.45, this is where xfce4 allows this setting to be customized.

Is it possible to achieve something similar in xterm?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Just had the following to `.Xresources`

`UXTerm*vt100.scaleHeight: 1.45`

Comment: Also via the command line `xterm -sh 1.45`. But the cursor looks horrible, protruding at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about that! It looks awful!