# How to set line height on Xterm?

Tags: xterm

There is already a question on it: [How to set line height in xterm?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616538/how-to-set-line-height-in-xterm)
but I don't have the "points" to comment yet, so I have to ask it again.

Environment:

- Ubuntu Jelly
- i3wm
- Xterm version 372
- tmux

I've tried now those things in my .Xresources file (yes, I have reloaded it with `xrdb -load .Xresources`):

```
! Line height:
! XTerm.vt100.scaleHeight: 1.5
! UXTerm*vt100.scaleHeight: 1.45
! XTerm*vt100.scaleHeight: 1.45
XTerm*Shading: 1.45
```

None of them work with and without tmux. But if I start one with `xterm -sh 1.45` it works.

How I can set the line height that it persists in my .Xresources?

Answer (score 1):

Lines beginning with `!` are comments.  Remove the `!` from the `XTerm` entry.

You can see the current setup with `xrdb -query`.

e.g.

```
$ xrdb -query | grep -i xterm
$ cat .Xresources
XTerm.vt100.scaleHeight: 1.5
$ xrdb -load .Xresources
$ xrdb -query | grep -i xterm
XTerm.vt100.scaleHeight:    1.5
```

Comment: Thank's @stephens Harris. I know that lines with ! in the beginning are comments. I've post them too, that people see my history of tries.
The command you've provided I have already in the list, but it doesn't has worked.

Comment: Yoiur example had the scaleheight line commented out.  You have a _shading_ line that is uncommented.

Comment: Yes! You are absolutely right. The command `XTerm.vt100.scaleHeight: 1.5` was my first try to set the line height. It doesn't worked, so I've commented it out. After that, I've tried `UXTerm*vt100.scaleHeight: 1.45`. It doesn't worked too, so I commented it out too. After that, I've tried `XTerm*vt100.scaleHeight: 1.45`. It doesn't worked too, so I commented it out too. After that, I've read in the article that I've post in my question the `xterm -sh 1.45` command, wich has worked, but is not persistent. So, I've set `XTerm*Shading: 1.45` in my .Xresources because it is it's equivalent, right?

Comment: Understand, the `-sh` is not shading. Man: `scale line-height values by the given number`. But why the command works, `XTerm.vt100.scaleHeight: 1.5` not (if it is not commented out)?

Comment: This command works: `XTerm*scaleHeight: 1.45`. In regular Terminal - one step further. But it doesn't work, if I start tmux.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was first, the wrong XTerm commands and second, after I've got the right command for the XTerm line height, one (or both) of the tmux plugins `tmux-resurrect` and `tmux-continuum` doesn't use the line height.

#### Solution

- First Step - XTerm:

  Put the following command in your `.Xresources` file:

  ```
  XTerm*scaleHeight: 1.45
  ```
- Second Step - tmux:

  - Log out from `tmux`:
    `lang-shell tmux detach`
  - Kill all tmux processes:
    `lang-shell pkill -f tmux`
- Third Step - Start on

  - Load `.Xresources` file:

    ```shell
    xrdb -load .Xresources
    ```
  - Start `tmux`:

    ```shell
    tmux
    ```

After this, in the whole terminal environment (`XTerm`, `tmux`, `Neovim`) the line height was correct ... in my case ^^